# C# DateTime vs SQL Server Date - type in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

If I have a C# `DateTime` object and a column in SQL Server of type `Date` (not `DateTime`)

For a stored procedure that takes in the date time from C# do I have any option other than passing in the C# `DateTime` as a SQL Server `DateTime` or can I pass it in of type `Date`?

Answer (score 1):

Define it as a `DATE` in your stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.YourProcedure (@FromDate DATE)
.....
```

and call it like this from C#:

```
yourSqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@FromDate", SqlDbType.Date);
yourSqlCmd.Parameters["@FromDate"].Value = yourDotNetDateTime.Date;
```

Comment: or just use ToShortDateString method... yourSqlCmd.Parameters["@FromDate"].Value  =yourDotNetDateTime.ToShortDateString()

Comment: @fabricio: **don't convert dates to string** unless you absolutely have to! That's a really really bad idea and causes issues with date/language settings and more - don't do it if it's soooo easy to avoid it!

Comment: Note that C# DateTime.MinValue exceeds the SQL Server Date minimum value. If that's an issue you either need to trap that in your code or use Date2 type (introduced in SQL Server 2008).

Comment: @ebpower: actually, your statement isn't quite true. The .NET `DateTime` exceeds the SQL Server `DATETIME` date range - but `DATE` in SQL Server **also** goes to `01/01/0001` (as does `DATETIME2`) so that should **not** be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the [DateTime.Date Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx)

> Gets the date component of this instance.

Comment: That still returns a `DateTime` object, just with the time set to 00:00:00.